# How to add html attributes and values for all lines quickly with vim and plugins?

Tags: html, awk, sed, sublimetext3, emmet

My os:debian8.

```
uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my base file.

```
home 
help 
variables 
compatibility 
modelines 
searching 
selection 
markers 
indenting 
reformatting 
folding 
tags 
makefiles 
mapping 
registers 
spelling 
plugins 
etc
```

I want to create a html file as bellow.

```
<a href="home.html" id="home">home</a>
<a href="help.html" id="help">help</a>
<a href="variables.html" id="variables">variables</a>
<a href="compatibility.html" id="compatibility">compatibility</a>
<a href="modelines.html" id="modelines">modelines</a>
<a href="searching.html" id="searching">searching</a>
<a href="selection.html" id="selection">selection</a>
<a href="markers.html" id="markers">markers</a>
<a href="indenting.html" id="indenting">indenting</a>
<a href="reformatting.html" id="reformatting">reformatting</a>
<a href="folding.html" id="folding">folding</a>
<a href="tags.html" id="tags">tags</a>
<a href="makefiles.html" id="makefiles">makefiles</a>
<a href="mapping.html" id="mapping">mapping</a>
<a href="registers.html" id="registers">registers</a>
<a href="spelling.html" id="spelling">spelling</a>
<a href="plugins.html" id="plugins">plugins</a>
<a href="etc.html" id="etc">etc</a>
```

Every line was added href and id  attributes,whose values are line content pasted `.html`  and line content itself correspondingly.

How to add html attributes and values for all lines quickly with vim and plugins?
sed,awk,sublime text 3 are all welcomed to solve the problem.

Comment: Why is "emmet" tagged?  Is this something you need to do in VIM?  Or could you use another editor?  Does it need to be automated or you want to know how to do it automatically?  Something like this is relatively easy using multi-line editing like is offered in SublimeText-- I am relatively certain plugins exist that provide similar support to VIM...

Comment: I like vim most ,to solve it with sublime text is welcomed too.

Comment: Are you using Linux, Windows or OSX?  I can write up a solution for this tailored to your OS.

Comment: debian 3.16.0-4-amd64

Comment: You can use embedded feature in vim for supporting wiki. Just open new file with .wiki extention, edit according .wiki syntax. For example wrap your words with `[[ .. ]]`. And do export to html `Vimwiki2HTML`. More info `:h vimwiki`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed is the best solution (simple and pretty fast here) if your are sure of the content, if not it need a bit of complexity that is better treated by awk:

```
awk '
   {
   # change special char for HTML constraint 
   Org = URL = HTML = $0
   # sample of modification
   gsub( / /, "%20", URL)
   gsub( /</, "%3C", HTML)

   printf( "<a href=\"%s\" id=\"%s\">%s</a>\n", URL, Org, HTML)
   }
   ' YourFile
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sed 's:.*:<a href="&.html" id="&">&</a>:' file
<a href="home.html" id="home">home</a>
<a href="help.html" id="help">help</a>
<a href="variables.html" id="variables">variables</a>
<a href="compatibility.html" id="compatibility">compatibility</a>
<a href="modelines.html" id="modelines">modelines</a>
<a href="searching.html" id="searching">searching</a>
<a href="selection.html" id="selection">selection</a>
<a href="markers.html" id="markers">markers</a>
<a href="indenting.html" id="indenting">indenting</a>
<a href="reformatting.html" id="reformatting">reformatting</a>
<a href="folding.html" id="folding">folding</a>
<a href="tags.html" id="tags">tags</a>
<a href="makefiles.html" id="makefiles">makefiles</a>
<a href="mapping.html" id="mapping">mapping</a>
<a href="registers.html" id="registers">registers</a>
<a href="spelling.html" id="spelling">spelling</a>
<a href="plugins.html" id="plugins">plugins</a>
<a href="etc.html" id="etc">etc</a>
```

Comment: Also, because you piqued my interest, I'm just going to plop some 3rd party [sed documentation](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) here for anyone else who might be interested.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to do this in `vi` itself, no plug-in neccessary

Open the file, type `:` and insert this line as the command

```
%s:.*:<a href="&.html" id="&">&</a>
```

it will make all the substitutions in the file.

Answer (score 3):

To complete this easily in Sublime Text, without any plugins added:

1. Open the base file in Sublime Text
2. Type `Ctrl+Shift+P` and in the fuzzy search input type `syn html` to set the file syntax to HTML.
3. In the `View` menu, make sure `Word Wrap` is toggled off.
4. `Ctrl+A` to select all.
5. `Ctrl+Shift+L` to break selection into multi-line edit.
6. `Ctrl+C` to copy selection into clipboard as multiple lines.
7. `Alt+Shift+W` to wrap each line with a tag-- then tap `a` to convert the default `<p>` tag into an `<a>` tag (hit `esc` to quit out of any context menus that might pop up)
8. Type a `space` then `href="` -- you should see this being added to every line as they all have cursors.  Also you should note that Sublime has automatically closed your quotes for you, so you have `href=""` with the cursor between the quotes.
9. `ctrl+v` -- this is where the magic happens-- your clipboard contains every lines worth of contents, so it will paste each appropriate value into the quotes where the cursor is lying.  Then you simply type `.html` to add the extension.
10. Use the right arrow to move the cursors outside of the quotes for the `href` attribute and follow the two previous steps to similarly add an `id` attribute with the intended `id`s pasted in.
11. Voila!  You're done.

Multi-line editing is *very* powerful as you learn how to combine it with other keyboard shortcuts.  It has been a huge improvement in my workflow.  If you have any questions please feel free to comment and I'll adjust as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
awk '{print a$1b$1c$1d}' a='<a href="' b='.html" id="' c='">' d='</a>' file
<a href="home.html" id="home">home</a>
<a href="help.html" id="help">help</a>
<a href="variables.html" id="variables">variables</a>
<a href="compatibility.html" id="compatibility">compatibility</a>
<a href="modelines.html" id="modelines">modelines</a>
<a href="searching.html" id="searching">searching</a>
<a href="selection.html" id="selection">selection</a>
<a href="markers.html" id="markers">markers</a>
<a href="indenting.html" id="indenting">indenting</a>
<a href="reformatting.html" id="reformatting">reformatting</a>
<a href="folding.html" id="folding">folding</a>
<a href="tags.html" id="tags">tags</a>
<a href="makefiles.html" id="makefiles">makefiles</a>
<a href="mapping.html" id="mapping">mapping</a>
<a href="registers.html" id="registers">registers</a>
<a href="spelling.html" id="spelling">spelling</a>
<a href="plugins.html" id="plugins">plugins</a>
<a href="etc.html" id="etc">etc</a>
```

Here I have created 4 variable a,b,c & d which you can edit as per your choice.

**OR**

```
while read -r i;do echo  "<a href=\"$i.html\" id=\""$i"\">"$i</a>";done < f
<a href="home.html" id="home">home</a>
<a href="help.html" id="help">help</a>
<a href="variables.html" id="variables">variables</a>
<a href="compatibility.html" id="compatibility">compatibility</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` one-liner:

```
while read v; do printf '<a href="%s.html" id="%s">%s</a>\n' "$v" "$v" "$v"; done < file
```

(OR)

```
while read v; do echo "<a href=\"$v.html\" id=\"$v\">$v</a>"; done < file
```

Comment: while read v; do printf '<a href="%s.html" id="%s">%s</a>\n' "$v" "$v" "$v"  >> newtest; done < test

Comment: @it_is_a_literature no, don't do the redirection once per input line inside the loop, do it once outside of the loop. You wouldn't really do this anyway though - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

To execute it directly in vim:

```
!sed 's:.*:<a href="&.html" id="&">&</a>:' %
```

Comment: Why would you want to bring up vim to call sed instead of just calling sed directly?

Answer (score 1):

In awk, no regex, no nothing, just `print` strings around `$1`s, escaping `"`s:

```
$ awk '{print "<a href=\"" $1 ".html\" id=\"" $1 "\">" $1 "</a>"}' file
<a href="home.html" id="home">home</a>
<a href="help.html" id="help">help</a>
```

If you happen to have empty lines in there just add `/./` before the `{`:

`/./{print ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
list=$(cat basefile.txt)
for val in $list
do
   echo "<a href=\""$val".html\" id=\""$val"\">"$val"</a>" >> newfile.html
done
```

Using bash, you can always make a script or type this into the command line.

Comment: `echo "<a href=\""$val".html\" id=\""$val"\">"$val"</a>"` should instead be written using printf as `printf '<a href="%s.html" id="%s">%s</a>\n' "$val" "$val" "$val"` to avoid the escaping quotes nightmare and for portability but that'd still leave you with a UUOC and other issues so don't do it...

Answer (score 0):

This vim replacement pattern handles your base file:

```
s#^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$#<a href="\1.html" id="\1">\1</a>#
```

- `^\s*` matches any leading spaces, then
- `.\{-}` captures everything after that, *non-greedily* — allowing
- `\s$` to match any trailing spaces.
- This avoids giving you stuff like `<a href="home .html" id="home ">home </a>`.

You can also process several base files with vim at once:

```
vim -c 'bufdo %s#^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$#<a href="\1.html" id="\1">\1</a># | saveas! %:p:r.html' some.txt more.txt`
```

- `bufdo %s#^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$#<a href="\1.html" id="\1">\1</a>#` runs the replacement on each buffer loaded into vim,
- `saveas! %:p:r.html` saves each buffer *with an html extension*, overwriting if necessary,
- vim will open and show you the saved `more.html`, which you can correct as needed, and
- you can use `:n` and `:prev` to visit `some.html`.

Something like sed’s probably best for big jobs, but this lets you tweak the conversions in vim right after it’s made them, use `:u` to undo, etc. Enjoy!